# Set newly created file as variable in makefile

Tags: bash, make, variable, buildroot

I am trying to create a file and set the contents of a file to a variable but the variable is always seen as empty.

An example:

```
define FILE_VAR
    cat /output/1.txt >> /output/2.txt
    $(eval s := $(shell cat /output/2.txt)) 
    $(eval FILENAME_BIN=$(word 1, $(s)).$(word 2, $(s)).$(word 3, $(s)).bin) 
    $(eval FILENAME_JFFS2=$(word 1, $(s)).$(word 2, $(s)).$(word 3, $(s)).jffs2)        
endef
```

Called via this as a post-gen hook:

```
# Alter the post-gen hooks, depending on what options are selected
ifneq ($(BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_FILE_VAR),)
    ROOTFS_EXT2_POST_GEN_HOOKS += FILE_VAR
endif
```

If `2.txt` exists before running this the variables will be set to the data prior to running make (not the new redirected data), if `2.txt` doesn't exist then the variables are not set. It looks like it is evaluating what the file is like when make is first run, which is not what I want.

Comment: Your makefile looks like a nominee for the "Useless Use of Cat" award.

Comment: This was cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609184/set-newly-created-file-as-variable-in-makefile

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify how `FILE_VAR` is used but if I try `$(eval $(FILE_VAR))`, then the problem is that `cat` does not do what you want outside a rule. Wrapping it in `$(shell )` might work better:

```
define FILE_VAR
    $(shell cat /output/1.txt > /output/2.txt)
    $(eval s := $(shell cat /output/2.txt))
    $(eval FILENAME_BIN=$(word 1, $(s)).$(word 2, $(s)).$(word 3, $(s)).bin)
    $(eval FILENAME_JFFS2=$(word 1, $(s)).$(word 2, $(s)).$(word 3, $(s)).jffs2)
endef

$(eval $(FILE_VAR))                                                                     

all:                                                                                    
    echo $(FILENAME_BIN)
```

And I used `>` instead of `>>` so 2.txt does not grow on every run.

Comment: I added how it is called, this all is building a filesystem through buildroot. Your solution did not help unfortunately. It's like the values at time of buildroot make are just set in stone if it's being read from a  file. I have no problem with delayed variable expansion for normal variables, just when reading from files.

Comment: @Paul you still don't show how `ROOTFS_EXT2_POST_GEN_HOOKS` is used. That's probably key to your problem. Figure this out and you will have a better chance at making it work without guesswork.